# Android SDK Manager doesn't load Extras

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to load Extras in SDK manager, but it doesn't work..
This is my screen: http://imgupload.sk/viewer.php?file=ncizvice2hov4ybpiiy3.png
How can I work?

Comment: Have you tried to open the "Extra" list?

Comment: ... then try menu Packages->Reload ...

Comment: I opened Extras list but there are nothing.. I tried to reload but nothing happens..

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing your cache (Tools > Options > Clear Cache), then reload (Packages > Reload).